# Alphabetical sorting of characters based on unicode order

Tags: python

The input's first line should start with the number of test cases. The following lines should contain test cases consisting of one or more words, delimited by a space. A word consists of any of the 256 characters of the Extended Ascii encoding.

Sample input:

```
3 
Good day
Hello there!
You're my #1!
```

Then, the output should output a line with unique characters (case insensitive) sorted alphabetically (based on unicode order) for each test cases, while ignoring white space.

Sample output:

```
adgoy
!ehlort
!#'1emoruy
```

I'm trying to think of ways to solve this, but I'm drawing a blank. How should I approach this?

Editing to add: I found these functions: ord() - to get unicode of character and chr() - to get the character of a given unicode

Answer (score 0):

let's call the string we want to sort by unicode `s`:

```
s = 'Good day'
```

first you need to remove the white spaces there are multiple ways one is `str.translate` with the following table:

```
s = s.translate({32: None, 9: None, 10: None, 13: None, 11: None, 12: None})
```

now since you want to ignore the case you need to call `.upper`, `.lower` or `.casefold` on your string an reassign it:

```
s = s.lower()
```

because you only want unique characters in your string you can convert it to a `set`:

```
s = set(s)
```

because a `set` is unordered you must convert it before you can sort it (in this case to a `list`)

```
s = list(s)
```

now you need to sort it by their unicode number:

```
s.sort(key=ord)  # do not reassign
```

and finally you need to reconvert it to a string:

```
s = ''.join(s)
```

It is sometimes considered a bad practice to use the same variable name in all steps because it can be hard to debug.
in the full code i combined some steps and varied the variable names:

```
def sort_by_unicode(s):
    s = s.translate({32: None, 9: None, 10: None, 13: None, 11: None, 12: None}).lower()
    l = list(set(s))
    l.sort(key=ord)
    return ''.join(l)
```